# Pass command line arguments to Gerrit and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

On Jenkins I have a maven job that I have configured using the gerrit trigger/event. Each time a change is pushed to the gerrit git repo the job is started automatically.

I have added a maven build profile to the job called **functional_test** which runs more tests and therefore takes longer time.

Now I would like to control if the profile should be activated or deactivated when a push is made to gerrit.

Is it somehow possible to pass parameters to gerrit when doing a push that either passes these parameters to the jenkins job or triggers another job which have the profile activated - would prefer the former?

Here it seems that they pass parameters in the commit message:
https://wiki.hpdd.intel.com/display/PUB/Changing+Test+Parameters+with+Gerrit+Commit+Messages

but its not documented how the parameters are parsed from there

Comment: You can always read the log message and parse that. How about having a special refs/for/functional_test branch that you link to to your job. Might be cleaner than polluting your commit messages

Comment: Ok since we are using a feature based branching strategy I guess it would look like this: refs/for/master/myfeature001/functional_test . I assume that nesting like this is ok?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure environmental variables in job configurations. In our project we have done like  `key=value export key` our ant targets reads this value. [this may help you](http://jenkins-le-guide-complet.batmat.cloudbees.net/html/sect-first-steps-first-job.html)

Comment: Yes I know that parameters can be defined in the job configuration, but how do I give these parameters values when I push my change to gerrit? Not much point in gerrit if developers most of the time must execute a job manually and thereby bypassing gerrit